# I have know idea how this is appending my list

Tags: python

I have made a list of all number from 0 to 500 and then I am looking for all number that end with a certain integer. The thing is I don't under stand how its working.

I am new to coding so don't know what to expect here or how it is working.

```
x = 0
y = []
while x <= 500:
    y.append(x)
    x = x + 1

a = 0
b = []
c = 0
# if i remove c from this or change c from 0 to 1 or any other number it just appends with that value
# but if c is as i have it, it some how appends the list with the values i am pulling with my if statment
while a <= 500:
    if int(repr(y[a])[-1]) == 0:
        b.append(c) 
    a = a + 1
    c = c + 1

    

print(len(b))
print(b)
```

Comment: There's no need for `c`, it's always the same as `a`. So just use `b.append(a)`

Comment: To get the last digit of a number, use `y[a] % 10`.

Comment: What's your actual question? "I don't understand how it's working" is too vague. How did you write it without understanding, you just put random code together and got lucky?

Comment: If you change `c`, then the numbers you add to your list will be offset from the numbers you want by the difference between `c` and `a`, because you're testing `a` but appending `c`, and they're different.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is

```py
c = 0
b = [x for x in range(501) if x % 10 == c]
print(len(b))
print(b)
```

Comment: ```range(x) ``` or ```range(0, x)``` starts from `0` and end with last number before  `x`. If your code was ```while x < 500:``` you should use ```range(500)```. But for ```x <= 500``` that equals to ```x < 501``` you should use ```range(501)```

Answer (score 0):

- `for x in range(...)` loops is better than `while` loops when start and end of loop are defined.
  so you can use this code to make y list:

```py
y = []
for x in range(501):
  y.append(x)
```

The shorter code is:

```py
y = [i for i in range(501)]
```

Or:

```py
y = list(range(501))
```

- For finding right digit of number you `% 10`
- For loop in a list you can use `for each_item in your_list:`
- In 2nd loop `a` and `c` are same, so you can use one of them:

```py
c = 0
b = []

for a in y:
  if a % 10 == c:
    b.append(a)
```

The shorter code is:

```py
b = [a for a in y if a % 10 == c]
```

- You can filter numbers where you create the list, so you can merge 2 loop in one loop only (ignore make y list):

```py
c = 0
b = []
for a in range(501):
  if a % 10 == c:
    b.append(a)
```

The shorter code is:

```py
c = 0
b = [a for a in range(501) if a % 10 == c]
```